# How to reset model in Blazor form?

Tags: c#, blazor

In my Blazor app I have a list of items. Clicking one of the items will open a dialog component with the item as a parameter. Within the dialog is an EditForm:

```
<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
        <EditForm Model="@Item" OnValidSubmit="SaveForm">
            <p><input type="text" @bind="@Item.Title" /></p>
            <p><input type="button" @onclick="Cancel" value="Cancel" /><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Item> Callback { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Item Item { get; set; } = new();
    public Item OriginalItem => Item; // <= First attempt

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        OriginalItem = Item; // <= Second attempt
    }

    async Task Cancel
    {
        Item = OriginalItem; // <= This doesn't work

        await Callback.InvokeAsync(null);
    }

    async Task SaveForm
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I change the `Item.Title` value and click the Cancel-button and the dialog closes, the Item model is still updated and I see the change in the list of items. That's how Blazor works, but not what I want in this case.

I try to "reset" the Item model by keeping a copy of the original Item model parameter and overwrite it in the Cancel-function, but that doesn't seem to work.

What is the right approach?

As far as I can see the opposite happens; clicking the Cancel-button sets OriginalItem = Item. I really don't get why.

Comment: You're not keeping a copy of the original object, you're keeping a copy of the reference of the original object, meaning, `Item` and `OriginalItem` both point to the *same* object in memory. Modifying one means modifying the other ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/26XXKy)). You'll probably want to *clone* (deep clone) the object if you want this to work with your current code. To do this, either manually implement a `DeepClone` method or use something proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78536/9363973)

Comment: To add to @MindSwipe comment, one approach is pull all your data from datastores as `records` - immutable objects.  You then create an editable class - which can populate itself from the record, and your editor uses that as the `EditContext`.  When you save/update you create a new `record` and submit that to your data store to save/update.  Or replace the existing object if it's not persisted.  You can use the notification pattern to trigger updates on any components that need updating.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I think I'll go with the serialize/deserialize method, that I can see most others use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered here [Modal with Parameters still apply changes after beeing canceled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311167/modal-with-parameters-still-apply-changes-after-beeing-canceled/71311445#71311445)

Comment: I had never thought that this would be so tricky. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your dialog is inside a Component which is passed a Parameter of type Item?
Anyway, I had the same issue as you and solved it quite easily.

Give your dialog component local properties.

```
Public string Title {get;set;}
```

In OnInitializedAsync, set your local properies to the value of your Item
properties

```
this.Title = Item.Title
```

Bind the Input field of the dialog to its local properties instead of Item properties.

```
<Input @bind=Title>
```

When you hit cancel just do nothing. Only close the dialog.

When you hit Save, set the Item properties to the value of local properties

```
Item.Title = Title
```

The should do the trick

Comment: Thanks. That would surely work, but the model has 20 og 30 properties already that I don’t want to specify one by one and also the solution is not easy to maintain.