# JSON cloning of DTO not working as expected

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

In continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72317155/how-to-reset-model-in-blazor-form) post I face a problem when cloning an object by serializing/deserializing it with Newtonsoft.Json.

The purpose:

From a list of `ItemView`'s I'm passing a `ItemView` parameter to a dialog/modal component with an EditForm.
If the user clicks the Cancel-button and the dialog closes I must "reset" the parameter so that any unsaved changes in the form is not reflected in the parent list.

Therefore, in my `OnInitializedAsync`, I'm cloning the parameter to an `ItemViewClone` object so that I can set `ItemView = ItemViewClone` when the user cancels the form.

Models:

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class ItemView
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public double Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Extension / cloning:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source , new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize, PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects }));
    }
}
```

Blazor component:

```
<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
        <EditForm Model="@ItemView" OnValidSubmit="SaveForm">
            <p><input type="text" @bind="@ItemView.Item.Title" /></p>
            <p><input type="button" @onclick="Cancel" value="Cancel" /><input type="submit" value="Save" /></p>
        </EditForm>
    </div>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<ItemView> Callback { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ItemView ItemView { get; set; } = new();
    public ItemView ItemViewClone { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ItemViewClone = ItemView.Clone(); // Or:
        ItemViewClone.Item = ItemView.Item.Clone();
    }

    async Task Cancel
    {
        ItemView = ItemViewClone; // <= Doesn't work
        ItemView.Item = ItemViewClone.Item; // <= This works
        await Callback.InvokeAsync(null);
    }

}
```

If I clone `ItemView` it doesn't work. When I edit `ItemView.Item.Title` and close the dialog without saving, I see the changes in the parent list.
But if I clone the `Item` inside the `ItemView` as also shown in the example, it works.

What could I be missing?

Cloning `ItemView` to `ItemViewClone` do work. It holds all the right values. It's the "resetting" that doesn't work.

Comment: consider binding your form to ItemViewClone *not* a parameter of the component. OnValidSubmit copy the properties that you expose on the form to the ItemView Parameter.

Comment: That’s not a bad idea. :) Must try that when I’m back in the office.

Comment: Now I've tried passing the clone as the form model. I can do the editing but when I save the form and set `ItemView = ItemViewClone` no changes happens. Also, I get an EF Core error when calling `.Update` that the {Id} is already being tracked. It seems like a good approach to work on a clone that just can be discarded, but I don't know if it can work?

Comment: Your using Blazor-Server you can only have one object tracked. So you need to update that object or create a new instance of the context.

Comment: I know. But how can I avoid that with this approach? I make a clone of the item in the list. Working on the clone and then lastly sets the item in the list quals to the clone; `ItemView = ItemViewClone`. Setting `.AsNoTracking()` on the list doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: `ItemView = ItemViewClone` is assigning the reference. Write a method to copy the properties. `ItemView.Blah = ItemViewClone.Blah` for all the properties exposed on your form.